# Need to develop Custom Delegate for API Calling

Tags: ios, delegates, nsurlconnection, appdelegate

I want to develop Custom Connection Class by which I can make API calls using it. I do not want to use any third party apis like afhttprequest or asihttp.

I want to develop my self this type of delegate. I have searched much things but I do not have much idea in CustomDelegates.

Comment: GAURAV its not very complicated thing just read custom delegate in detail so you can easily do that.

Comment: I am using this tutorial for developing but facing issue when i am importing it in the class where i want to use. It says no protocol found.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Comment: means this is your first time of create custom delegate?

Comment: yes its my first time.

Comment: Delegation is an object oriented design pattern. Think about what you have to do first and then decide what(if any) patterns you should use. As far as the delegate pattern is concerned - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Comment: i understood that concept but i am not able to understand how can i develop Custom classes for api. because their are lost of thing i am not getting in it. I want to understand that . @pe60t0

Answer (score 2):

I wrote one example of custom delegate.

1. From ViewController.m we call method with two number for addition of another class (Addition class)
2. Addition class will add these two number and call delegate method so we can get answer of that two number in ViewController using custom delegate.

---

### Addition.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    // write protocal for this class
    // you can give any name of that protocol

    @protocol AdditionDelgate <NSObject>
    // delegate method of this delegate
    -(void)answerOfTwoNumberAddition:(int)ans;
    @end


        @interface Addition : NSObject
        {

        }
        // set property of that protocol, so using that we can call that protocol methods (i.e. ansOfYourAns)
        @property (nonatomic, weak) id <AdditionDelgate> delegate;
        -(void) addThisNumber:(int) firstNumber withSecondNumber:(int)secondNumber;

        @end
```

---

### Addition.m

```
#import "Addition.h"

@implementation Addition

    -(void)addThisNumber:(int)firstNumber withSecondNumber:(int)secondNumber
    {
        int ans = firstNumber + secondNumber;

        // call delegate method of "AdditionDelgate" protocol
        // we already set delegate of viewController to this protocol
        // so it will call viewController class "answerOfTwoNumberAddition" method
        [self.delegate answerOfTwoNumberAddition:ans];
    }
    @end
```

---

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// import addition class
#import "Addition.h"

// set AdditionDelgate to class 
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AdditionDelgate>
@end
```

---

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // creat object of class
    Addition * additionObj = [[Addition alloc] init];
    // set delegate as self to that so that methods delegate methods will call
    additionObj.delegate = self;
    // call method
    [additionObj addThisNumber:2 withSecondNumber:3];
}

#pragma mark ----- Delegate method of Addition view ----
// this is delegate method of Addition class, it will call from "addThisNumber" method line of code
// ([self.delegate answerOfTwoNumberAddition:ans];)

-(void)answerOfTwoNumberAddition:(int)ans
{
    NSLog(@"addition of two number is %d",ans);
}

@end
```

---

I hope it will help you

Comment: I understood this example. But what i inherit other delegate in custom delegate. I am inheriting the NSURLConnectionDelegate in my custom delegate.

Comment: so inherit your class from NSURLConnectionDelegate and add your custom methods in that. just keep in mind always call super class methods from child class